# URI simplification in java

Tags: java, uri

I have several strings that are being combined to make a URI.  I want to ensure that the resulting URI is as simple as possible. For example, given

```
str1 = "/dir1/dir2";
str2 = "./dir3/";
```

I want to end up with `"/dir1/dir2/dir3/"` not `"/dir1/dir2/./dir3/"`.

Is there a Java library that performs this kind of simplification?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JDK7 has a [Path.normalize](http://download.java.net/jdk7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html#normalize%28%29) method which removes redundant name elements from a path. It also contains [Path.resolve](http://download.java.net/jdk7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html#resolve%28java.lang.String%29) which can be used to join two paths.

Take a look at the [Java Tutorial | Path Operations](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/pathOps.html) for more information.

Answer (score 4):

try the class `java.net.URI`

```
  URI uri = new URI("http://localhost/");      
  System.out.println(uri.resolve("dir1/dir2/./dir3/"));
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess [`URI`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URI.html) can don that kind of job, no ?

Answer (score 0):

If the [URI](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URI.html) class doesn't do what you want, there is more flexibility and power in the [UriBuilder](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ws/rs/core/UriBuilder.html) class.